# Difference between continuous and non-continuous data .

Tags: descriptive-statistics, continuous-data, discrete-data, qualitative

In a dataset "survey", pulse and age are given as non-continuous data. how come these age and pulse can be non-continuous?

this is the reference link
https://explorable.com/discrete-variables

Answer (score 1):

Some times, there is no additional benefit from recording some ones age as, e.g. 43.2367. So instead, it is recorded as 43. Same goes with pulse.